# Unhandled inspector error - {"code":-32000,"message":"Object reference chain is too long"} in selenoid

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenoid

- Selenoid version - 1.10.0
- Chrome version - 85.0
- Docker image - selenoid/vnc_chrome:81.0

Exception -

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Object reference chain is too long"}
(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'mani-zt254', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4b9:53da:b2d:19d3%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 80.0.3987.87, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.g10u57}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:45089}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept}
Session ID: 53b76f85512a10c9c08655240eef4042
```

**Scenario**

The above exception occurs while finding an element/performing any operation using **jquery 1.x** versions
So I inject the latest **jQuery 3.5.0** able to perform the actions using jquery but some pages some jquery methods conflict occur due to this some errors occur in browser console click is not working in some elements, the above problems are there **chrome 80.0** and above versions, now I'm using **chrome 85.0**.

Answer (score 0):

Probably instead of calling:

```
evaluate_script
```

You should call:

```
execute_script
```

To elaborate. There is not so much information in the question itself, but in the feature test, if you are calling a script to be executred, you should call it with `execute_script` and not with `evaluate_script`

But there is not so much information in the question form a year or so, so just giving a wild quess.

Comment: This helped me workout the prooblem described by the OP